# easy way to make an insert to OrientDb using its REST API

Tags: rest, orientdb

In order to make SELECT query to OrientDb REST API I have to make GET request  by a URL, like `http://localhost:2480/query/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql/traverse * from %239:23`. It is easy.

In order to make INSERT command, like `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19`, to OrientDb REST API, I have to make POST request with a content

```
 {content: { "@class": "V", name: 'jack', boss: '#11:19'}}
```

[image]

So I have to convert string `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19` to JSON

```
 {content: { "@class": "V", name: 'jack', boss: '#11:19'}}
```

The problem is that I have to do it during runtime, using regular expressions, because I don't know exactly the content of my INSERT query, it's a variable. I believe, such a "string to json" conversion is potentially bugFull. It will throw an error on some INSERT query.

My question is: Is there  another approach for making INSERTs to OrientDB, using its REST API, without converting `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19` to `{content: { "@class": "V", name: 'jack', boss: '#11:19'}}` ?

## Update

The previous POST request for inserting is totally incorrect, it is not equivalent to `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and better to insert without converting `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19` to `{content: { "@class": "V", name: 'jack', boss: '#11:19'}}`.

Just put query `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19` instead of json.

[image]